# TensorFlow predict User's next number

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

**UPDATED**

So my goal is to create a machine learning program that takes a list of training numbers given by a user, and try to predict what number they might pick next. I am fairly new to machine learning, and wanted to make this quick project just for fun. Some issues that I am running into include: not knowing how to update my training labels to correspond to training for the next number and how to go about predicting that next number. Here is my current code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # I will add a visualization and other things later


train_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
train_labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
test_number = 2    # These values will be changed into inputs later to collect individual data

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)),    # Is this the correct way to input my data? I want 1 number to pass through here
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')    # Later I want to input any number I want, but for now I will output a prediction number 1-10
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(train_numbers, train_labels, epochs=2)    # I am not sure if my fitting here works, my code does not make it here

predictions = model.predict(test_number)
print(predictions)
```

Here is my current error and traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mason Choi/PycharmProjects/machine_learning/experimentation.py", line 23, in <module>
    predictions = model.predict(test_number)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1569, in predict
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1105, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 650, in __init__
    self._internal_adapter = TensorLikeDataAdapter(
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 275, in __init__
    num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs))
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 275, in <genexpr>
    num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs))
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 887, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key].value
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help welcome, THANKS!

Comment: For each sample you need to provide a label, that's what error message says actually.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, but how can I actually implement this? Should I make a dataframe with numbers 1-10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to map a function, then they need to contain same number of samples. For example here you want to map `Y = X`.

```
train_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
train_labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Your output size should consist of `(1,)` as you want to predict a single *continuous* number. So last layer should be:

```
keras.layers.Dense(1) # linear layer
```

Also metrics should be appropriate for your problem(regression):

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mae'])
```

You can [find the available metrics from here](https://keras.io/api/metrics/).

**Edit**: Pass the numbers that you want to predict as a `numpy` array:

```
test_number = np.array([2])
predictions = model.predict(test_number)
```

Also in this case, you can try `sgd` optimizer instead of `adam`.

```
keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
```

Having softmax with 1 neuron is a big mistake, your model will output `1` everytime. Above, I did not specify any activation, so I made that output neuron `linear`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I know understand how the training works, however I am still confused as to how to predict a new value using the  trained model. I have updated my question to include a new error and explanation.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, with all of these changes when I input a list of numbers 0-9 (for example: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) and predict for the number 2, the prediction should return something like 3 in the best possible case, right? After running the model a few times, it does not seem to be very great, but is always between 2 and 3, so its ok. To make it better, can I just feed the same training data 5 times for a better result? (like: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0...)???

Comment: Also, I just realized that my model.fit is fitting my input train numbers to my train_labels. When I collect a user sequence of 10 numbers 0-9, should I assign the train_labels variable to them instead? So sorry for bombarding you with questions, but you really have made a big difference and I really appreciate it.

Comment: To make it better, increase the number of epochs(that's not the case always), do not duplicate your data like `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`. You can introduce new data to model like `0 1 2 3 ... 17 18`. `fit()` method assigns them, just past the *fit* method your inputs(features) and corresponding outputs(labels).